# Read remote server event log to get AD user logon and logoff events and save it to SQL

Tags: c#, sql, authentication, active-directory, logoff

Does anyone know how to get the user logon and log-off event logs from a SERVER 2012 Active directory into SQL server using C#? I would preferably run the service from a remote computer.

Your assistance is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [LogParser](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=24659) its a Microsoft command line tool for querying things like event logs and IIS log files.  I have seen it used to filter event logs (but not the security logs).  From memory the syntax is pretty fussy.  You can shell out a call to log parser form C#, output to a text file, then read the file and import to SQL Server.

e.g.

LogParser.EXE -i:EVT "SELECT TimeGenerated,EventTypeName FROM System WHERE TimeGenerated > '2014-03-25 00:00:00' " > C:\TodaysEvents.csv

I think you can access remote servers too using FROM \\RemoteServer\System

Edit:  I just checked:  There is an option to query Active Directory in log parser.  Use the -i:ADS option

Comment: Thank you Tom, I will test this ASAP!!